# Optimize Reporting in Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have 10 reports and 250 customers. All the reports are ran by my customers and each report take parameters. Depending on the parameters, same report connects to different database and gets result. I know with different parameters caching is not an option. But I dont want to run these reports on live data during day time. Is there anything I can do (snapshot, subscription) that can run overnight and either sends these reports or save a snapshot that could be used for next 24 hours?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As M Fredrickson suggests, subscriptions might work here depending on the number of different reports to be sent.

Another approach is to consolidate your data query to a single shared datasource. Shared datasources can have caching enabled, and there are several options for refreshing that cache, such as on first access or on a timed schedule. See [MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636149.aspx).

The challenge with a cached datasource is to figure out how to remove all parameters from the actual data query by moving them elsewhere, usually the dataset filter in the report, or into the filters of the individual data elements, such as your tablixes.

I use this approach to refresh a 10 minute query overnight, and then return the report all day long in less than 30 seconds, with many different possible parameters filtering the dataset.

You can also mix this approach with others by using multiple datasets in your report, some cached and some not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the issue is, to accomplish that, we need to change a lot in the reports, which we do not want to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going the route of subscriptions.  [While you could do some fancy hack to get multiple snapshots of a single report](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2007/01/12/per-user-snapshots-or-multiple-snapshots-for-a-report-each-with-different-parameters-at-the-same-time.aspx), it would be cleaner to use subscriptions.

However, since you've got 250 customers, and 10 different reports, I doubt that you'll want to configure and manage 2,500 different subscriptions within Report Manager... so I would suggest that you [create a data driven subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx) for each of the reports.

Comment: Before you get too far with data driven subscriptions, make sure that you will be deploying to SQL Server Enterprise edition. Standard edition SQL Server does not support data driven subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem is we use standard edition and that cannot use data drive subscription. so, i have to go with either subscriptions or snapshots.

Comment: You could write SQL queries or .NET code to create and change the subscriptions in bulk. But this would require custom code.

Comment: It turns out i can create snapshot programmatically. But the problem is when I try to show them, I have to use "Go To URL" option in the action of the textbox, which opens up a new browser window and requires authentication. My users are already logged into my site and do not need to know the authentication for the reporting services and I do not want to provide them the authentication. Is there anything else I can do? I cannot use "Go To the Report" Option, it complains about illegal characters. Please let me know if anyone solved similar issues. Thanks.